# Can querying an non-unique index return multiple values?

Tags: sql, database, indexing, database-design, database-indexes

I have a table

```
UserId - PK

SubscriptionId 

Date
```

Multiple users can have the same subscriptionId, and I want to query all the user who have this subscription. So I was thinking of adding an non-unique index on subscription ID so I can efficiently do this query.

However, I'm a bit unsure how this index should be structured. I'm currently stuck on whether the index should just be SubscriptionId itself or a composite index of (SubscriptionId, UserId)?

I'm wondering what's the query's behaviour in either? and which one would give me the desired output which is to look up all the user under a certain subscription ID.

Comment: The composite index of (SubscriptionId (descending), UserId) allows you to more easily return the rows in UserId order.  This index can (and should) be unique to prevent duplicate SubscriptionId, UserId rows.

Comment: Does  (SubscriptionId (descending), UserId)  return multiple rows? This index is unique. However, the access pattern I'm looking for here is to get all the users under a subscription ID, where the same subscription ID can have multiple different user ID associated. In this case, should I just create a non-unique secondary index on SubscriptionId?

Comment: An index doesn't return anything.  Use a WHERE SubscriptionId = date on your SELECT statement;

Comment: You want an index - to improve performance and/or ensure data consistency?

Comment: Can a user switch subscriptions? If the answer is yes, then use a unique constraint on UserId. A combined Subscription/User index would then be useful to help performance of queries. If subscription is mandatory and required for uniqueness then make it a compound unique constraint - but if you are referencing this data through any foreign keys, then you may still want to use an immutable integer primary key so that you can make change to subscription should the need arise and not lose the FK relationships. i.e. it really is dependent of your requirements.